# Why is my WPF-Button not clickable?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, wpf-4.0

I've got a strange thing goin on here. I'm designing a small program with Visual Studio 2010 using WPF and VB.Net but for some reason, all my buttons and checkboxes (didn't test more items) aren't clickable anymore! Even if I drag a pretty new one out of the VS-Toolbox!
They've got all "IsFocousable" and "IsHitTestVisible" and "IsEnabled"-Setting set to "True". Does someone has an idea to fix that!?

Greetz!

Husky110

Comment: Does this happend in one project that you're working on or in every project?

Comment: what about their container? Is it enabled too?

Comment: okay got it! the first grid had "IsHitTestVisible = False"

Comment: so it was my fault, thx for the input ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it was my fault...

Turns out that one of the parent controls of my button had IsHitTestVisible as false

Comment: For people using WindowChrome: 
WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"